# Are Kotlin callback functions multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, callback

In the example below (from Kotlin docs), there are nested callback functions.

Assuming `postItem` is called on the main thread, is it true that immediately after calling `preparePostAsync` the main thread continues it's execution without waiting for `preparePostAsync` to finish?

If yes, does this mean that Kotlin is actually performing multi-threading under the covers of callback functions? (Assuming this is true, would it mean that the number of callbacks = number of threads?)

```
fun postItem(item: Item) {
    preparePostAsync { token -> 
        submitPostAsync(token, item) { post -> 
            processPost(post)
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not related to multi-threading, then what is the difference between callback functions and multi-threading?

Comment: This has nothing to do with what Kotlin is doing, and everything to do with the decisions made by the implementation of `preparePostAsync` and `submitPostAsync`.  Those functions might invoke those callbacks on other threads, or not; Kotlin doesn't make that decision for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the API you're working with. Those examples in the docs are imaginary ones, not part of the standard library.

Typically, when a function takes a callback, it returns immediately after enqueuing the request, and will call the callback on the main thread when a result comes back.

Network libraries like OkHttp use a thread pool under the hood, so there is not necessarily a one-to-one correspondence of running background threads to number of requests made.

The word "callback" is just an informal name for asynchronous tasks that follow this pattern.

Comment: So callbacks are not related to multithreading, unless there is an explicit usage like with OkHttp. In a scenario where there are no network connections or thread creations in a callback chain, the main thread first will execute everything in callback chain and only after that it will execute following code which would be outside of the callback chain? On the other hand if the callback chain used new thread in between, then the main thread would pause executing callback chain and would switch executing code outside of callback chain until the new thread is done executing?

Comment: "Callback" is an informal term for a pattern. You could write something that follows a similar pattern but doesn't behave the typical way. You could write a function that takes a "callback" parameter and simply calls it immediately, but then it wouldn't fit the concept of a callback, and would also be pointless.

Comment: The main thread of a UI framework (like Android or Swing or JavaFX) has a message queue. Typically, asynchronous callback functions do their work and then post the callback to the main thread queue, so even if the function taking a callback parameter doesn't do multi-threading, when it posts the callback code to the queue, it will not run until everything currently in the main thread queue is already completed. The callback pattern is sometimes used for UI drawing/animation events, which don't really involve multithreading.